# RStudio Server on Rasperri Pi - dependency psmisc error

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-wheezy

I am trying to install RStudio server on my Rasperry Pi. But I get the error "Dependency not satisfiable: psmisc". I am new to both Rasperry Pi and Debian/Wheezy, but I am eager to learn, so please bear with me.

Any hint on where to look or what to do is greatly appreciated!

Thank you for your time.

David

**The long version is this:**

R-base is installed with: `sudo apt-get r-base`, which worked fine.

I installed gdebi-core for unkown reasons (I followed the official guide from [here](http://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download-server/)): `sudo apt-get install gdebi-core`.

And I downloaded the RStudio Server .deb file: `wget http://download2.rstudio.org/rstudio-server-0.98.1102-i386.deb`

I tried to install the file: `sudo gdebi rstudio-server-0.98.1102-i386.deb`, however, I got the error "this package is uninstallable Wrong architecture 'i386'", which I could "fix" with: `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt-get update`

However, if I try to install it again, I now get the erroe "dependency is not satisfiable: psmisc"

I also tried to update the psmisc package with `sudo apt-get install psmisc` but it returned 0 upgrades, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.

Comment: You can't change the arch like that an expect it to work. You downloaded a file designed to run on a 32 bit x86 based architecture (e.g. Pentium and the like), and are trying to get it to run on an arm processor. Unless you can find a download designed for the arm it won't work. Also, since R is designed for numerical analysis of large data sets have you considered what the performance is likely to be?

Comment: Ah, that with the arch makes sense! :)
The performance will be an interesting part as well. It probably will turn out to be an interesting proof of concept...
Anyway, thanks for the direction

Answer (score 2):

In your post, `wget http://download2.rstudio.org/rstudio-server-0.98.1102-i386.deb` indicates the debian package is based on i386 architecture. Raspberry Pi uses ARM CPU. Thus, CPU architecture does not match.